# I want to pick up smart contract from different and utilize it into one, how do you think I can?

Tags: hardhat, smart-contract-wallets

I want to build an Nft and art piece sharing projects using hardhat, polygon and solidity and I want to follow different contract from different tutorial to add different functionality.

Comment: Consider using Foundry instead - here's a link to the [Foundry Book](https://book.getfoundry.sh/), which includes a tutorial on how to create an NFT contract.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.